# Django 1.9.5 filebrowser 3.7.2 image not showing and in template image url is wrong

Tags: python, django, image, django-filebrowser

filebrowser
127.0.0.1:8000/admin/filebrowser/browse/?
upload file success

[image: upload file image]

image url href: href="media/uploads/chrysanthemum.jpg"
but the url is wrong.

```
"/media/uploads/chrysanthemum.jpg"
```

this url is right.

"_versions/chrysanthemum_admin_thumbnail.jpg">

is wrong

"/media/_versions/chrysanthemum_admin_thumbnail.jpg">

is right.
settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'grappelli',
    'filebrowser',
    'django.contrib.admin',
  ]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ("images",os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'images').replace('\\', '/')),
    ("css",   os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'css').replace('\\', '/')),
    ("js",    os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'js').replace('\\', '/')),
)
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + "grappelli/"
site.directory = "media/uploads/"
site.storage.location = BASE_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media').replace('\\','/')
```

directory:
[image: directory]

Answer (score 0):

settings.py
remove two rows

```
site.directory = "media/uploads/"
site.storage.location = BASE_DIR
```

Because MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT were setted up. And  Filebrowser is right